# how to add another function to change screen button?

Tags: android

I have used belove code to change the screen of app By clicking a button.

```
Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    addListenerOnButton();


}


public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, App2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);   

        }

    });

}
```

I want to add another function to same button to send a sms programmatically.
I change above code like this.But it does not work.

```
Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    addListenerOnButton();


}


public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, App2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);   

        }

    });

}


protected void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


      findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendSMS();
        }
    });

    }
private void sendSMS()
{

   try {
 SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
 ArrayList<String> smsString = sms.divideMessage("XXXX");
 sms.sendMultipartTextMessage("XXXXX", null, smsString, null, null);
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Sent..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    catch(Exception exp){
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sending failed...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }

}
```

anyone can help me to solve this.?
I want add both fuctions to same button,to work at same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button only have ONE clicklistener. Inside of it you code the two functionts.

```
Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {
    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            sendSMS();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, App2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);   
        }
    });
}
```

If you want to do it parallely put the sendSMS() function inside a thread.

Answer (score 0):

You did not call `onCreate1` anywhere so the code inside it will never be run. That's why the second listener is never added. Even if it is called, a button can only have one listener anyways. You can just call `sendSMS` after or before you start a new activity:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, App2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);   
        sendSMS(); // here!
    }

});
```